# I am facing error "The toolchain is unable to build a dummy C file" while building simple hello world application on cmd

Tags: cmake, qemu, zephyr-rtos, gnu-arm

I am facing error "**The toolchain is unable to build a dummy C file**" while building simple hello world application on **cmd**. I have Windows 10 64 bit machine.
I have installed all necessary tools and packages for Windows as per instructions on website (https://docs.zephyrproject.org/1.13.0/getting_started/installation_win.html) .
I have installed GNU ARM Embedded from the ARM developer website: (https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads)

I also tried to run on **CMake GUI** and got same error. Please advice .
I am attaching the screenshots below: Please advice. I have tried with other boards also like reel_board but still facing same issue.

[CMDError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gqyq.png)

[CMakeGUIError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX3TY.png)

[CmakeErrorLog File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXWCj.png)

Comment: It seems you are trying to target an x86 system using an ARM compiler.  I wouldn't expect that to work.  The directions said to try "-DBOARD=nrf52_pca10040" for ARM targets, but screenshot shows "-DBOARD=qemu_x86".

Comment: @fdk142 I tried with nrf52_pca10040 . But got same error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we prefer **textual** representation of a code/a program's output/logs to the *images*. Please, add "CMDError", "CmakeErrorLog File" parts into the question post as **text**. See also [ask].

Comment: I must be missing some setting or this may also be compatibility issue with my system.... i have finally found another method to successfully run and build the zypher application by. 1. installing WSL subsystem for linux on windows.    2 installing ubuntu app from Ms store     3. installing zypher sdk , zipher, cmake , west and other python dependencies using ubuntu commands mentioned on under Linux section of zephyr documentation website.....no need for chocolatey or gnu emu toolchain